# How to draw 1D mesh with polynomial order?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw both the approximated solution and the mesh (including the polynomial order). The example I have in mind is the following: (from http://dx.doi.org/10.1201/9781420011692)
[image: 1]

My attempts result in the following pgfplots code:

```
\documentclass[border={2pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\plotwidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\plotheight}{7cm}
% this is the data of the solution that will be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
    X       My_solution
   0.0       0.000
  0.2       0.180
  0.5       0.159
  0.7       0.107
  1.0        0.000
}\solution

% this is the data of the mesh that will also be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
x y  order
%
0    0  1
0.2  0  1
0.2  1  1
0 1     1
%
0.2 0  2
0.5 0  2
0.5 1  2
0.2 1  2
%
0.5 0  3
0.7 0  3
0.7 1  3
0.5 1  3
%
0.7  0  5
1    0  5
1    1  5
0.7  1  5
%
}\mesh


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=master,width=\plotwidth,height=\plotheight,]
% draw the solution in the master axis
\addplot[solid, line width=1pt] table[x=X, y=My_solution] {\solution};
\end{axis}

% this axis contains the mesh (with orders)
\begin{axis}[
colorbar right,
  colorbar style={
    at={(master.right of north east)},
    height=\plotheight/1.5,
} ,
width=\plotwidth,
%place the colorbar with repesct to the master axis
at={(master.above north west)},
enlargelimits=false,
enlarge x limits=true,
axis lines=none,
height=2cm,
ticks=none,
 ]
 % draw the patches that will represent the mesh
    \addplot [patch, patch type=rectangle, point meta=explicit,line width=1pt,faceted color=black]  table[meta=order] {\mesh};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

The result is not so far from the one expected, but there are still unsolved issues:

1. I used patches to draw the mesh, but I am not sure that it is the best way to proceed. Furthermore, I would like that the height of that axis to be the same as the default width than the colobar width: `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colorbar/width},` but the compiler complains that it provides a too small plot. This is a minor issue.
2. The colorbar that gives the legend of the colors is harder to handle correctly:

   - I need it to be discrete and the label to be located in the middle of the color cell. For that, I tried `colormap access=direct` and `colorbar sampled` as well as `colorbar style={ytick=data,y tick label as interval=true,}` but none of them provide a correct output.
   - I need the height of the colorbar to be size-related to the master axis, preferably of the same size. The following command is not working `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/master axis height}`

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question - I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Is this answer what you request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this closer to your demand ? I just modified some parameter from your example, but this is far too long as a comment. The most important modifications are related to `scale only axis` that make `with={}` and `height={}` apply to only the drawing area, which makes sizing of the `colorbar`s easier.

```
\documentclass[border={2pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\plotwidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\plotheight}{7cm}
% this is the data of the solution that will be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
    X       My_solution
   0.0       0.000
  0.2       0.180
  0.5       0.159
  0.7       0.107
  1.0        0.000
}\solution

% this is the data of the mesh that will also be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
x y  order
%
0    0  1
0.2  0  1
0.2  1  1
0 1     1
%
0.2 0  2
0.5 0  2
0.5 1  2
0.2 1  2
%
0.5 0  3
0.7 0  3
0.7 1  3
0.5 1  3
%
0.7  0  5
1    0  5
1    1  5
0.7  1  5
%
}\mesh


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlarge x limits=false,
scale only axis,name=master,width=\plotwidth,height=\plotheight]
% draw the solution in the master axis
\addplot[solid, line width=1pt] table[x=X, y=My_solution] {\solution};
\end{axis}

% this axis contains the mesh (with orders)
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis,
colorbar right,
  colorbar style={
    at={(master.right of north east)},
    height=\plotheight,
    ylabel={Colorbar Label},
    ylabel style={yshift=6ex},
} ,
width=\plotwidth,
%place the colorbar with repesct to the master axis
at={(master.north west)},
anchor=south west,
%enlargelimits=false,
enlarge x limits=false,
axis lines=none,
height=5mm,
ticks=none,
]
 % draw the patches that will represent the mesh
    \addplot [patch, patch type=rectangle, point meta=explicit,faceted color=black]  table[meta=order] {\mesh};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** : A slight improvement

```
\documentclass[border={2pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\plotwidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\plotheight}{7cm}
% this is the data of the solution that will be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
    X       My_solution
   0.0       0.000
  0.2       0.180
  0.5       0.159
  0.7       0.107
  1.0        0.000
}\solution

% this is the data of the mesh that will also be provided with a file
\pgfplotstableread{
x y  order
%
0    0  1
0.2  0  1
0.2  1  1
0 1     1
%
0.2 0  2
0.5 0  2
0.5 1  2
0.2 1  2
%
0.5 0  3
0.7 0  3
0.7 1  3
0.5 1  3
%
0.7  0  5
1    0  5
1    1  5
0.7  1  5
%
}\mesh


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=false,
    scale only axis,
    name=master,
    width=\plotwidth,
    height=\plotheight
]
% draw the solution in the master axis
\addplot[solid, line width=1pt] table[x=X, y=My_solution] {\solution};
\end{axis}

% this axis contains the mesh (with orders)
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    colormap={example}{samples of colormap={6,sample for=const}},
    colormap access = const,
    colorbar right,
    colorbar style={
        samples = 6,
        at={(master.right of north east)},
        height=\plotheight,
        ylabel={Colorbar Label},
        ylabel style={yshift=6ex},
        ytick={1,2,3,4,5},
        yticklabel style = {yshift=-5ex},
        point meta min = 0,
        point meta max = 5,
    },
    colorbar sampled,
    width=\plotwidth,
    %place the colorbar with repesct to the master axis
    at={(master.north west)},
    anchor=south west,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    axis lines=none,
    height=5mm,
    ticks=none,
]
% draw the patches that will represent the mesh
    \addplot [patch, patch type=rectangle, point meta=explicit,
              faceted color=black,
              colormap={example}{samples of colormap={6,sample for=const}},
              colormap access = const,
              ]  table[meta=order] {\mesh};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Perfect!! For my practical use, I need to set all the shifts and number according to point meta max=\MaxP where \MaxP can be read from the files and corresponds to the largest order of approximation.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @VincentDarrigrand Excuse me, is that a question ?